# Alter ownership of a table in a schema does not work

Tags: postgresql, permissions

```
create role schema_owner;
create role table_owner;
```

Current signed in role is `postgres`

```
create schema test;
grant schema_owner to postgres;
grant table_owner to postgres;
alter schema test owner to schema_owner;
```

This Works....

```
create table test.t1 (a int);
alter table test.t1 owner to table_owner;
```

This last statement doesn't work. Why ?

> Error is : permission denied for schema test

Why the postgres user cant change the owner of table t1 in schema test to table_owner. Postgres is a already a member of table_owner and schema_owner? How can I achieve this?

Comment: I cannot reproduce that. But then, `postgres` is a superuser in my cluster. You should provide a more complete example that includes how you created `postgres`.

Comment: This is a PAAS service. As a user I don't have access to the superuser. Think of postgres as the admin user of the server and also the owner of the database in which the above statements are run.

Comment: Still that should not happen. Chances are that your service provider has hacked the PostgreSQL permission system somehow. Try to reproduce the problem with real PostgreSQL. If you can, please provide a complete script. If you cannot, the problem is between you and your hosting provider.